# onclick input not loading function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is some jquery that will update two div's with content from an ajax.php

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
setTimeout(function() {
        var postData = " "; 
        $.ajax({
            url : 'ajax.php', 
            data : postData}).done(function( resp ) {
                $('#div_1').text($('#inner_1' , resp).text());
                $('#div_2').text($('#inner_2' , resp).text());
            }
    );
}, 100);
</script>
```

This loads fine when I open the page, but it won't also load with a an on-click button:

```
<input type="button" value="Update" onclick="function()" />
```

Much appreciated!

Here's the final solution with an event listener, thanks for the answers!

```
<html>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.pack.js" language="javascript"></script>


<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
var ping = function() 
{
    var postData = " "; 
    $.ajax
    ({
     url : 'ajax.php', 
     data : postData}).done(function( resp ) 

        {
            $('#div_1').text($('#inner_1' , resp).text());
            $('#div_2').text($('#inner_2' , resp).text());
        }
                            )
}
    setTimeOut(myFunction, 100);
    document
        .getElementById("button")
        .addEventListener("click", myFunction, false);
</script>

   <div id="div_1"></div>
   <div id="div_2"></div>

<input type="button" value="Update" onclick="ping()" />

</html>
```

Comment: Is your function called function?

Comment: You need to move your code from the lambda function in `setTimeout` to a separate function that you can call onclick, and then change your code to `setTimeout(function() { <your function name>() });`

Comment: `function function() { ... }`? how what why when?

Comment: Please don't use inline event handling. You're using jQuery, you can use the `click()` method even if you don't want to use native JS.

Comment: Can I ask why you're putting a `setTimeout` to start with? Are you trying to wait for the dom to be ready? A better method would be `$(document).ready(function()...);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usage of *inline event handling by advocation* (which is the approach you are using) is **heavily discouraged**, instead use [**event listeners**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers); however, according to your question, what you need to do is to declare a non-anonymous function, store it into a variable and use it as the parameter for `setTimeOut` and call in on your `onclick`:

On your javascript:

```javascript
var myFunc = function() {
    var postData = " "; 
    $.ajax({
        url : 'ajax.php', 
        data : postData}).done(function( resp ) {
            $('#div_1').text($('#inner_1' , resp).text());
            $('#div_2').text($('#inner_2' , resp).text());
    }
);

setTimeout(myFunc, 100);
```

On your HTML:

```html
<input type="button" value="Update" onclick="myFunc()" />
```

Also, you can't use the reserved word `function` as a variable or a function name.

Better still, here's an example using **event listeners** instead:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    var myFunction() {
        /* Your function here */
    }
    setTimeOut(myFunction, 100);

    document
        .getElementById("YourButton")
        .addEventListener("click", myFunction, false);
</script>
```

Comment: This answer encourages inline event handling by advocation. -1

Comment: @SterlingArcher that's just a matter of opinion, the answer is what the OP wants.

Comment: @arielnmz No, it's not "a matter of opinion", it's a known bad practice.

Comment: @SomeKittensUx2666 it's still as opinion based as, say, mysqli vs mysql extensions. But I've stated it on the answer though.

Comment: @arielnmz if most of the community agrees that it's a bad practice, it's beyond that of an opinion, don't you agree?

Comment: "mysqli vs mysql extensions" -- nobody should ever use the mysql extension. It is deprecated and should not be used.

Comment: @arielnmz if you really, truly believe that using deprecated language functions is 'a matter of opinion', please stop answering questions on this site.

Comment: @SomeKittensUx2666 calm down, I was just answering the OP's question, I in no way encourage its use, I've even noted that at the very beginning of the answer.

Comment: Just for the record: The `mysqli` vs `mysql` was just an example and the fact that some function is deprecated or not encouraged to use doesn't have anything to do with the certainty of an answer. Yes, it's discouraged and I've stated so in the answer. And no, the fact that it's a bad practice doesn't make an statement technically incorrect, not even misleading, but only not useful.